# How to do a array_merge and receiving only arrays without index?

Tags: php, array-merge

For example, this is my 2 arrays :

```
$array1 = [ 'espagnol' => ['ola' => 'ketal', 'mue biene' => 'si']];
$array2 = ['français' => ['salut' => 'ça va', 'très bien' => 'oui']];
```

If I do an array merge I will get this array :

```
'espagnol' => ['ola' => 'ketal', 'mue biene' => 'si'],
'français' => ['salut' => 'ça va', 'très bien' => 'oui']
```

I would like this kind of array :

```
['ola' => 'ketal', 'mue biene' => 'si'],
['salut' => 'ça va', 'très bien' => 'oui']
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to get only the values from an array

```php
$newArray = array_merge(array_values($array1['espagnol']), array_values($array2['français']);
```

Comment: For this example it works, but if the key is an int and you don't know it, how do you process ?

Comment: There is a corresponding function called `array_keys()` that will tell you the keys of your array. If you don't know the overall structure of your array then I suppose you could do something with `array_walk()` and then use `is_array()` on each element, and if it returns true get the values from it.

Comment: Im' not sure if I well understood but I'm gonna try thx